# Installing phpMyAdmin in http://localhost/ (instead http://localhost/phpmyadmin)

Tags: apache, centos

How to I set up my Apache server to show phpMyAdmin as my "default site" (http://localhost)?

There is an alias

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

in my phpMyAdmin Apache configuration (/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf).

So I've added the following line:

```
Alias / /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

But for some reason this doesn't work.

localhost/phpmyadmin -> Works

localhost/ -> 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias should be like this :-

`Alias / /usr/share/phpMyadmin/`

A trailing slash ('/') must be there otherwise apache will interpret it as `/usr/share/phpMyAdminindex.html` which actually does not exists.

Also you can create a **VHost** for this and point your **document root** to the location of phpMyadmin.

For RHEL/CentOS base OS default location is `/usr/share/phpMyadmin`.
Grant proper permission to apache for accessing this location and you can than access it through http://localhost/.

Comment: Why would I need a virtual host for that? As I said, everything works fine if I use `Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin` (or any other alias except `Alias / /usr/share/phpMyAdmin`). What do you mean by _"grant proper permission to apache for accessing this location"_?

Comment: Because your apache is configured on localhost. Your phpmyadmin is not configured on your default doc root. when you access http://localhost it will by default hit your doc root (/var/www/html/) not your phpmyadmin directory.

Comment: And by granting proper permission means apache should be able to read your /usr/share/phpMyadmin directory.

Comment: _"it will by default hit your doc root (/var/www/html/) not your phpmyadmin directory."_ But that's why I'm adding `Alias / /usr/share/phpMyAdmin` to my config. This line should tell Apache to look in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin if someone accesses localhost/.

Comment: _"apache should be able to read your /usr/share/phpMyadmin directory"_ Apache can read /usr/share/phpMyAdmin as phpMyAdmin works if you access it via http://localhost/phpmyadmin (as stated in my original post).

Comment: I just created new server and this is doing what you ask for

Comment: Thanks, but that really wasn't necessary. ;) It's not that I didn't believe you. I'd just like to know why my solution doesn't work. Why can't you simply define an alias which points Apache to the corresponding location? Why do you need a virtual host? I still don't understand that.

Comment: @Lugaxx You are right in this case Alias should work.. No need for VHost.. I again tested your alias condition and finally solve the problem. I was facing same error page than I looked in logs and problem was in permissions. So what we have to do is add a trailing ' / ' in `/usr/share/phpMyadmin/` so this would be `Alias / /usr/share/phpMyadmin/`. This will work for sure... You can test on same IP 52.62.5.226/.

Comment: Now when we were using `Alias / /usr/share/phpMyadmin` then apache is looking for `/usr/share/phpMyAdminindex.html` file which is not present. And actual file is `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/index.html`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. But the actual answer to my question is that you need this final slash (/). I don't know how to point that out. Anyway, thanks again, and have a nice day.